# Como mostrar Data desde un segundo Array en ReactTable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ayuda en Reactjs: Como mostrar los datos que están dentro del segundo Array "Other", solo se muestran los que están en el primer Array ejemplo d.Code si imprime

```
    const data = [...this.state.info];

    return (
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={[
            {
              columns: [
                {
                  Header: "Code",
                  id: "code",
                  width: 50,
                  accessor: d => d.Code
                },
                {
                  Header: "Other",
                  id: "other",
                  width: 50,
                  accessor: d => d.other.Skills //???
                },

              ]
            }
          ]}
        />
);
```

Mi Array es (Modificado)

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "https://link.com#",
    "value": [
        {
            "Code": "A1",
            "Name": "Erick",
            "Email": "test@gmail.com",
            "Other": [
                {
                    "Skill": "test!!",
                    "Ref": "test!!"                                     },
                }
             ]
        }
     ],
    "odata.nextLink": /more/?$skip=10"
}
```

Comment: tú código tiene una errata: `d.other.Skills` debería ser `d.Other.Skill`

Comment: Si! lo cambie,, aun sigue sin mostrar los Skill

Comment: El array no es un array y también tiene erratas, por favor, pulsa en [edit] y arregla la pregunta un poco. Deberías leer el [tour] y crear un [mcve]

Comment: @PabloLozano gracias, acabo de pegare array tal cual, el hecho es que si me imprime los demás valores que no están dentro de Other. Saludos

Comment: El problema es que `Other` es un array también, tendrías que recorrerlo (si tiene varios elementos) o usar `Other[0].Skill` si estás seguro de que sólo tendrá un elemento

Comment: @PabloLozano como podria hacer esa parte? intente   
accessor: d => d.Other[0].Skill, pero me da error este error en el accessor TypeError: Cannot read property 'Skill' of undefined

Comment: Eso significa que el parámetro Other[0] no existe, seguramente no siempre tenga datos.

Comment: @PabloLozano pero asi como está en el ejemplo es que lo tengo todos los campos funcionan menos los de Other, no se como llamarlos, y los campos dentro de Other si existen.  no se si es que hay que hacerlo de otra forma en el ReactTable. que dices?

Comment: Prueba a poner  `accessor : d => d.Other && d.Other.length ? d.Other[0].Skill`

Comment: @PabloLozano gracias! funcionó.. esa era la solución!, ,